# Launch Excel from Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, hyperlink, localhost

I have a website that will always runs on my `localhost` so I was wondering if I can directly launch excel files.

I see a post here [Launch file:// from Firefox or Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374927/launch-file-from-firefox-chrome) with this as solution

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "file:///[[PUT SERVER NAME HERE]]";);
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled",  "allAccess");
```

but as my site will run on `localhost` I would like to know if there are any other ways, I even tried `file://` but it opens a download dialog.

I am only interested in firefox solution but others will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="file:///C:\sample.xls">test</a>
```

Works for me in all browsers. (open file dialog pops. hope you don't think FF will open the excel file natively, as it won't.)